# Assign Vertex Group from Evaluated Vertices

Tags: python, vertices, depsgraph

I am writing an operator that allows to pick a surface in the 3D view and assign a vertex group to the hit surface. It's working perfectly fine for objects where the evaluated vertex count matches the original vertex count, but as soon as the evaluated object is effected by a modifier (e.g. mask) that changes the vertex count, there is a mismatch between evaluated and original vertex count (and indices). As vertex groups can only be assigned to the original object (as far as I know), I need a way of getting the original vertex indices from the evaluated ones that the user selected.

As my operator is relatively big and has some additional dependencies, I won't post the whole thing here, but I will add the relevant parts below in hope that it helps.

```py
# 1. Cast a ray and use the returned face_index to find the (evaluated) vertex indices (island_ids)
# 2. Assign the ids to the returned hit object (original)
vg.add(island_ids, 1, 'ADD')
```

Currently, I am considering too approaches:

1. Get the original indices from the evaluated ones, by using the location. Probably with a kdtree.
2. Disable all generative and geometry changing modifiers before starting the operator. This would be my last resort...

I hope I explained the problem and somebody has a solution. Help is much appreciated! :)